# QueryLocator generates scope of the Object

Tags: apex, soql, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch, sosl

I am recently working with building apex batch job and I came across Database.QueryLocator which I believe can create scope of the object which is passed to the execute() method. I do not understand what does the scope means? What data type is QueryLocator and what does it actually has. Does it return rows of a table stored in database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scope is of type `SObject` which can be cast to specific objects (Like Account, Contact, etc).

The `querylocator` object is described [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_database_batch.htm).

It has two different methods

- `getquery`
- `Iterator`

> In Batch Apex `getQueryLocator(query)` creates a QueryLocator object used in batch Apex or Visualforce.

```
public static Database.QueryLocator getQueryLocator(String query)
```

Comment: Can you tell me what is the difference between Database Class and SOQL,DML operations directly? what are the use case of using them?

Comment: Database class provides more flexibility like dynamic query ,dynamic DML where you know the query string but not sure of objects and fields .You construct objects and field names on fly .Also Database DML provides more flexibility of error handling ,partial success or failures .Database is a system class and you can go through various methods to discover the power

Answer (score 4):

A QueryLocator (or, formally, [Database.Querylocator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_database_batch.htm)) represents a server-side database cursor; you use cursors to iterate over very large amounts of data (salesforce allows up to 50,000,000 rows per batch class start method).

The variable named "scope" in the context of a batch class simply means "the records relevant to the current iteration of the execute function." You don't need to call it "scope," as only the data type is important. I usually write my execute method as `public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, SObject[] records)`.

You can also use QueryLocator outside of a batchable context, but this is an incredibly rare usage, since you can't normally query more than 50,000 rows per transaction anyways (except for read-only Visualforce). One common use is actually instantiating a [StandardSetController](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_ApexPages_StandardSetController_ctor.htm).